# Cakephp3 Shell class for "Queue" could not be found

Tags: shell, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

Hi have one shell on cakephp3 and on my laptop its running well and its doing what is expected (the line used /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/page/bin/cake queue )

Then i have push everting to server in ubuntu, update composer, the debug set to true, and i have run /var/www/html/api/bin/cake queue
And this what i received:

```
<?
namespace App\Shell;

use Cake\Console\Shell;
use Cake\Mailer\Email;

class QueueShell extends Shell
{

    public function initialize()
...
...
...
    }
}Exception: Shell class for "Queue" could not be found. in [/var/www/html/api/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Console/ShellDispatcher.php, line 295]
```

I have change just for testing chmod of everting  to 777, but that didn't work.

When i run /var/www/html/api/bin/cake it confirm that queue is there.

```
    Welcome to CakePHP v3.2.4 Console
---------------------------------------------------------------
App : src
Path: /var/www/html/api/src/
PHP : 5.5.9-1ubuntu4.14
---------------------------------------------------------------
Current Paths:

* app:  src
* root: /var/www/html/api
* core: /var/www/html/api/vendor/cakephp/cakephp

Available Shells:

[Bake] bake

[DebugKit] benchmark, whitespace

[Migrations] migrations

[CORE] i18n, orm_cache, plugin, routes, server

[app] console, queue

To run an app or core command, type `cake shell_name [args]`
To run a plugin command, type `cake Plugin.shell_name [args]`
To get help on a specific command, type `cake shell_name --help`
```

Someone have some suggestion what can be missing in the server, or to be changed?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you sure that you have [**short open tags**](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.short-open-tag) enabled?

Comment: Or bettter yet: Why not using proper `<?php` tags as everyone else? :)

Comment: You are right -_-
I am using in all the remaining code the proper <?php but fail on this file ....